Can you tile a 15x16 rectangle using eight rectangles whose sizes are 1x2, 2x3, 3x4, ... 8x9?
Can you tile a 15x16 rectangle using eight rectangles whose sizes are 1x2, 2x3, 3x4, ... 8x9?
No two rectangles can be the same size.

Answer:

 Yes you can and this is one way you can do it:
 


When you say "this is how you do it", do you mean there's a unique solution (modulo symmetries), or is it just some introduction text?

All I meant was this is how you can do it.

Oh :x I was trying to see if there are possible variations and it's not obvious to me. The top-right and bottom-right rectangles force the bottom-right to stick to an edge, or a self-contradiction is reached. So there may well be a unique solution, but I'm not sure.

@MatthieuM. Note that the two rectangles at the top left can be swapped.

@ACB: Good call. So there's at least 2 distinct solutions.

Already answered, just to say there are ten ways to do it. I would have trouble counting them but my tiling program normally gets it right... if I type in all the parameters correctly. I think the right hand two are the pair already posted. The other eight correspond to 2x2x2 as there are three flippable pairs.

 

